# Suppress ERRORLEVEL In Single Command

Tags: bamboo, keil, errorlevel

I am using Atlassian's Bamboo to build a project, and the way I'm doing it asks for the executable and any parameters I want to send to it. Therefore, this is *not* a batch file. When the executable finishes, it sets the error level to 1, indicating "warnings" in compilation. I really could care less about these warnings, but Bamboo sees the ERRORLEVEL=1 and fails the build.

Basically, what I'm after is to be able to call a "failing" command, AND reset ERRORLEVEL in the same line. *Basically*...

```
set %ERRORLEVEL%=1 THEN set %ERRORLEVEL%=0
```

I have a really bad feeling that this isn't possible...and I also don't think it is possible to set the compiler to ignore warnings from the command line. Therefor, I need to change how Bamboo is building this project.

Comment: How about just fixing the code so that it doesn't generate warnings? Solves the entire problem cleanly.

Comment: I wish it were that easy. It's not my code. I'm just handling the Bamboo side of things. I can tell the developer to "fix the problem", but that only gets me so far.